# Body of View is not rerendered

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am making QuizApp. Currently I have viewModel in which questions are fetched and stored in @Published array.

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let repository: QuestionRepository

    @Published var questions: [Question] = []
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = .init()

    init(repository: QuestionRepository){
        self.repository = repository
    
        getQuestions()
    }

    private func getQuestions(){
        repository
            .getQuestions()
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                receiveValue: { [weak self] questions in
                    self?.isLoading = false
                    self?.questions = questions
                }
            )
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func updateQuestions(){
        questions.removeFirst()
    
        if questions.count < 2 {
            getQuestions()
        }
    }
}
```

In `QuestionContainerView` HomeViewModel is created as @StateObject and from it, first data from `questions` array is used and passed to `QuestionView`.

```
@StateObject private var viewModel: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel(repository: QuestionRepositoryImpl())

var body: some View {
    if viewModel.isLoading {
        ProgressView()
    } else {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            if let question = viewModel.questions.first {
                QuestionView(question: question){
                    viewModel.updateQuestions()
                }
            } else {
                Text("No more questions")
                    .font(.title2)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

`QuestionView` has two properties, `Question` and `showNextQuestion` callback.

```
let question: Question
let showNextQuestion: () -> Void
```

And when some button is pressed in that view, callBack is called after 2.5s and after that viewModel function `updateQuestions` is called.

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    let question: Question
    let showNextQuestion: () -> Void

    @State private var showCorrectAnswer: Bool = false
    @State private var timeRemaining = 10

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
        Text("\(timeRemaining)")
            .font(.title2)
        
        Text(question.question)
            .font(.title2)
            .padding()
        
        ForEach(question.allAnswers, id: \.self){ answer in
            Button(
                action: {
                    showCorrectAnswer.toggle()
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
                        showNextQuestion()
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    Text(answer)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .padding()
                        .background(getBackgroundColor(answer: answer))
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                }
            )
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        if timeRemaining > 0 {
            timeRemaining -= 1
        } else {
            showNextQuestion()
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to pass first item from viewModel array to QuestionView and after some Button action in QuestionView I wanted to remove firstItem from array and pass next firstItem.

But problem is that QuestionView is not updated (it is not rerendered) and it contains some data from past item - I added timer in QuestionView which is counting down and when question is changed, timer value is still same as for before question, it is not reseted.

I thought that marking viewModel array property with @Published will trigger whole `QuestionContainerView` render with new viewModel first item from array, but it is not updated as I wanted.

Comment: It’s hard to say without a [mre]. My guess is that you have nested `ObservableObject`s. Is that the case?

Comment: Not your problem with the view, but your `getQuestions` isn't correct - It will add a new subscriber each time it is called and effectively leak it (assuming that `repository.getQuestions()` returns a new publisher.  You could remove all from `storage` before adding the new subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the SwiftUI code, one or all could contribute to the problem, here are the ones I noticed:

1. We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI for view data, that's the job of the `View` struct and property wrappers.
2. When `ObservableObject` is being used for model data, it's usually a singleton (one for the app and another for previews) and passed in as `environmentObject`. We don't usually use the reference version of `@State`, i.e. `@StateObject` for holding the model since we don't want model lifetime tied to any view on screen, it has to be tied to the app executable's lifetime. Also, `@StateObject` are disabled for previews since usually those are used for network downloads.
3. In an `ObservableObject` we `.assign(to: &$propertyName)` the end of the pipeline to an `@Published var`, we don't use `sink` or need `cancellables` in this case. This ties the pipeline's lifetime to the object's, if you use `sink` you need to cancel it yourself when the object de-inits (Not required for singletons but it's good to learn the pattern).
4. Since your timer is a `let` it will be lost every time the `QuestionView` is re-init, to fix it needs to be `@State`.
5. `ForEach` is a View not a for loop. You have either supply `Identifiable` data or an `id` param, you can't use `id:\.self` for dynamic data or it'll crash when it changes.